# Im getting an error code 1822 when i making the TAG table

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

```sql
create database priceTag;
use priceTag;

CREATE TABLE `ProductNumber` (
  `Sku` INT auto_increment not null,
  `Model` VARCHAR(100),
  PRIMARY KEY (`Sku`)
);

ALTER TABLE ProductNumber AUTO_INCREMENT=60000;


CREATE TABLE `Manufacture` (
  `Manufacture` VARCHAR(100),
  `Model` VARCHAR(100),
  `Category` VARCHAR(100),
  PRIMARY KEY (`Model`)
);

CREATE TABLE `OpenBox` (
  `Condtion` VARCHAR(100),
  `LP` INT auto_increment not null,
  `MissingItems` VARCHAR(100),
  `Model_` VARCHAR(100),
  FOREIGN KEY (`Model_`) REFERENCES `Manufacture`(`Model`),
  PRIMARY KEY (`LP`)
);

ALTER TABLE OpenBox AUTO_INCREMENT=200000000;

CREATE TABLE `TAG` (
  `SKU*` INT,
  `Model*` VARCHAR(100),
  `PRICE*` DECIMAL(10,2),
  `LP*` INT,
  `condtion*` VARCHAR(100), 
  FOREIGN KEY (`SKU*`) REFERENCES `ProductNumber`(`Sku`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`Model*`) REFERENCES `Manufacture`(`Model`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`LP*`) REFERENCES `OpenBox`(`LP`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`condtion*`) REFERENCES `OpenBox`(`condtion`)
);

CREATE TABLE `Inventory` (
  `INV` int,
  `Sku!` int,
  `Model!` VARCHAR(100),
  FOREIGN KEY (`Sku!`) REFERENCES `ProductNumber`(`Sku`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`Model!`) REFERENCES `Manufacture`(`Model`)
);
```

Comment: Always provide **complete and unchanged** error message, not a small part of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column which you refer on in `` FOREIGN KEY (`condtion*`) REFERENCES `OpenBox`(`condtion`) `` (i.e. `OpenBox.condtion`) is not indexed.

Add needed unique index creation then create `TAG` table.

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bb691202463cbe06b37844961557b39c)

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code, and then ran `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` to get more detailed information about the error.

> ---
>
> ### LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
>
> 2021-12-02 09:47:16 0x700007565000 Error in foreign key constraint of table test2/tag:
> FOREIGN KEY (`condtion*`) REFERENCES `OpenBox`(`condtion`)
> ):
>
> Cannot find an index in the referenced table where the
> referenced columns appear as the first columns, or column types
> in the table and the referenced table do not match for constraint.

It's complaining about this foreign key:

```
FOREIGN KEY (`condtion*`) REFERENCES `OpenBox`(`condtion`)
```

The `OpenBox.condtion` column is not a primary key or unique key. Foreign keys must reference a key of the parent table.

You already have another foreign key in your TAGS table referencing the `OpenBox` table. Are you intending that the `condtion` column of the respective row be copied to the TAGS table? That's not how foreign keys are intended to be used.